# How to identify careless responders when items negatively correlate with the total scale

Tags: r, reliability, data-preprocessing, cronbachs-alpha, item-analysis

I'm calculating the Cronbach's alpha on a [dataset](http://178.62.83.15/COPE.csv) with the scores of the Coping Orientations to the Problems Experienced (COPE-NVI-25) with the R package `psych`. I used the following code:

```
alpha(data[, 73:97])
```

But got this error:

> Some items ( COPE.5 COPE.19 COPE.22 ) were negatively correlated with the total scale and probably should be reversed.

The items have already been correctly reversed when necessary, so I suppose that I have to identify and exclude some careless responders. How I can do that?

Comment: Two questions: (1) ¿how big is your data set? and (2) ¿are you making an attempt to distinguish between careless and disingenuous responders?

Comment: 799 people answered the questionnaire. From this initial sample 386 responses were excluded because incomplete or invalid. I would like to identify those responses that cause the items to correlate negatively and exclude them. So both careless and disingenuos if possible...